# Optimal pythonic way to achieve result output

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need some help regarding optimal and good solution for my answer.

I have input dict like this:

```
a = {
 (1, 1403): {1:0.1, 2:0.1, 3:0.2},
 (1, 1412): {1:0.1, 2:0.1, 3:0.2},
 (1, 1411): {1:0.1, 2:0.1, 3:0.2},
 (1, 1402): {1:0.1, 2:0.1, 3:0.2},
 (1, 1411): {1:0.1, 2:0.1, 3:0.2},
 (2, 1501): {1:0.1, 2:0.1, 3:0.2},
 (2, 1511): {1:0.1, 2:0.1, 3:0.2},
 (2, 1700): {1:0.1, 2:0.1, 3:0.2},
 (2, 1120): {1:0.1, 2:0.1, 3:0.2},
 (2, 2133): {1:0.1, 2:0.1, 3:0.2},
 (2, 2130): {1:0.1, 2:0.1, 3:0.2},
 (2, 901): {1:0.1, 2:0.1, 3:0.2},
 (3, 1111): {1:0.1, 2:0.1, 3:0.2},
 }
```

I want Output like this:

```
{1: { 1403: {1: 0.1, 2: 0.1, 3: 0.2}, 
      1402: {1: 0.1, 2: 0.1, 3: 0.2}, 
      1411: {1: 0.1, 2: 0.1, 3: 0.2}, 
      1412: {1: 0.1, 2: 0.1, 3: 0.2}}, 

 2: {1120: {1: 0.1, 2: 0.1, 3: 0.2}, 
     2130: {1: 0.1, 2: 0.1, 3: 0.2}, 
     1700: {1: 0.1, 2: 0.1, 3: 0.2}, 
     901: {1: 0.1, 2: 0.1, 3: 0.2}, 
     1511: {1: 0.1, 2: 0.1, 3: 0.2}, 
     1501: {1: 0.1, 2: 0.1, 3: 0.2}, 
     2133: {1: 0.1, 2: 0.1, 3: 0.2}}, 
 3: {1111: {1: 0.1, 2: 0.1, 3: 0.2}}}
```

I have done code below

```
data_dict = defaultdict(dict)
for (a,b), c in a.items():
    data_dict[a].update({b:c})
```

I had already above answer to achieve my desired output, Is it good approach? 
Are there any better solutions to achieve result (in pythonic way), must be optimal.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: No better solution than this? @Di

Comment: Maybe someone else will have a better approach, but I would have done it the same way u did, it's easy to read.

Comment: @Ding I think good geeks are going to tell better approaches.

Comment: `data_dict[a].update({b:c})` is a bit obtuse. `data_dict[a][b] = c` has the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use dict comprehension, as described in [PEP 274](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), which might be more pythonic.
However, the naive solution `result = {a: {b: c} for (a, b), c in a.items()}` does not work as desired. (It will give you a dictionary with three keys, each containing *one* dictionary).

There might be some trickery in the dict comprehension that would allow the desired behavior, but it would seem that the code would not become very readable, or understandable, thus rendering it very *unpythonic*.

In short, your own solution would be quite pythonic.